# Why is -1L * -9223372036854775808L == -9223372036854775808L

Tags: c#, .net, math, f#, binary

I understand this has something to do with the way processors treat overflows, but I fail to see it. Multiplication with different negative numbers gives either zero or `-2^63`:

In C# Interactive:

```
> return unchecked (-1L * -9223372036854775808L);
-9223372036854775808
> return unchecked (-2L * -9223372036854775808L);
0
> return unchecked (-3L * -9223372036854775808L);
-9223372036854775808
> return unchecked (-4L * -9223372036854775808L);
0
> return unchecked (-5L * -9223372036854775808L);
-9223372036854775808
```

In F# Interactive:

```
> -1L * -9223372036854775808L;;
val it : int64 = -9223372036854775808L
> -2L * -9223372036854775808L;;
val it : int64 = 0L
> -3L * -9223372036854775808L;;
val it : int64 = -9223372036854775808L
> -4L * -9223372036854775808L;;
val it : int64 = 0L
```

I came to this because it surprised me in F# until I realized that F# by default operates in unchecked contexts. Still, I couldn't readily explain the behavior.

I do understand why `9223372036854775807L + 1L == -9223372036854775808L`, I just don't get it for multiplication with a negative number and why it alternates between `0` (binary all zeroes) and `-2^63` (binary most significant bit 1, rest zeroes).

Interestingly, this holds with the [rule of multiplicative identity](http://www.coolmath.com/prealgebra/06-properties/08-properties-multiplicative-identity-01), i.e., since `-1L * -9223372036854775808L == -9223372036854775808L`, it follows that `-1L * -1L * -9223372036854775808L == -9223372036854775808L` and since `-1L * -1L = 1L`, it shows that the identity law still holds.

Comment: Bound to be a duplicate, but there is one more negative value for signed types - this has the fun property that `abs(int)>0` is not always true

Comment: windows calculator gives same results. and not just for QWord but for any size of numbers (i.e Word, Byte...). I think that's something related to 2's complement and the way its calculated.

Comment: Isn't the way to multiply by -1 in two's complement to take the complement and add 1? Taking the complement gives `9223372036854775807L` and adding 1 gives you the result back what you started with.

Comment: Note (i) that your quantity -9223372036854775808L is in fact -2^63, not -2^64.   (ii) that -2^63 is in fact represented as a 1 in the sign bit and the rest of the bits 0; the bit pattern of all 1's represents -1.

Comment: @mike, spot on, you're absolutely right, fixed now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers you are getting are all correct modulo 2^64: that is, they differ from the mathematically correct answers by a multiple of 2^64, and that's a reasonable definition of a correctly truncated answer.

I'll use ≅ to relate two numbers that are congruent modulo 2^64.  Thus

- -1 * -2^63 = 2^63 ≅ -2^63
- -2 * -2^63 = 2^64 ≅ 0
- -3 * -2^63 = 3 * 2^63 = 2^64 + 2^63 ≅ -2^63

and so on.  Note that 2^63 and -2^63 are congruent, but it is -2^63 that is representable according to the conventions of twos-complement arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior is expected due to how negative numbers are represented in 2's complement.

Now assume you have 8 bits.

```
1000 0000
```

This is `-128`(signed). it can be also translated to `128`(unsigned)

Multiplying it by `-1` will be like this

```
1000 0000  (*1)=> 1000 0000 (negate)=> 0111 1111 (+1)=> 1000 0000
```

Which in 8 bits overflows and you get `-128` again. (oh and don't forget the maximum value you can get here is `127` **not** `128`. because the MSB is used for sign)

Multiplying it by `-2` will be like this

```
1000 0000  (*2)=> 1 0000 0000 (negate)=> 1111 1111 (+1)=> 1 0000 0000
```

And since this value in 8 bits overflows you get `0`

Comment: Did you mean the multiply by two negate step to be 1110 1111 1111? It seems to make sense, but is this also the reason it behaves this way?

Comment: in mathematics you can have `9` bits. and MSB will be the 9th bit. getting `1110 1111 1111` would not make much sense because those bits does not exist. fixed the answer. and for processors I think `OF` and `CF` flags will be set to `1`. 9th bit just doesn't fit. @Abel

Comment: I understand, just asking because in an earlier edit you had 3 nibbles. But yeah, makes sense. The carrier bit is probably set in these overflow cases.

Comment: 1000 0000 "can be also translated to 255" -- as an unsigned number, it would be 128.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: oh, yes thanks for the correction. missed that @MikeSpivey

Comment: @M.kazem: what you've done here (using 8 bits not 64 for clarity) is show that one proposed algorithm for signed multiplication produces the results shown in the question.  But we don't know if that algorithm is in fact used by any machine, and you have done nothing to show that the algorithm is correct.  The approach I've tried to use in the other answer is to define carefully what it means for a result to be correct (i.e. congruence to the true result mod 2^64) and then show that the values in the question are the correct ones.  That way we need not ask about the algorithms that are used.

Comment: @MikeSpivey you are right. I appreciate your answer and comment. btw I'm student so I'm learning things. this is the basic answer that I tried to give from what I just understood today :D .